# TLMGR was working, now is looking in wrong directory for texlive.tlpdb

Tags: tlmgr

I have no idea of whether this `tlmgr` problem has anything to do with my `arara` problem, but they seem to have arisen at the same time (see [...run ConTeXt with Arara...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679661/texworks-run-context-compiler-from-arara?noredirect=1#comment1691318_679661)).
I solved a convoluted problem with `tlmgr` just a couple of months ago ([tlmgr_1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676877/sudo-tlmgr-gui-does-not-recognize-my-su-admin-privilege-flags-command-not?noredirect=1#comment1681509_676877)and [tlmgr_2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675507/update-problems-tlmgr?noredirect=1#comment1679796_675507)), after which `tlmgr`worked seamlessly. I tried to run `tlmgr` today, and this was the dialog from the terminal:

```
username@computername:~$ sudo tlmgr gui
[sudo] password for username:            
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
Loading local TeX Live database
  (/root/texmf/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb)

>>NB>>> this file actually exists; BUT it's at /home/username/texmf/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb !!

This may take some time, please be patient ...
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /root/texmf
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5285.
```

For convenience, the tlmgr code lines 5279 thru 5296 are:

```
See https://tug.org/texlive/distro.html#perltk for more details.
Goodbye.
";
      }
    } else {
      printf STDERR "$prg: unexpected problem loading Tk: $@\n";
    }                       <this is line 5285<<<<<<
    exit 1;
  }

  # now check that we can actually create a top level window,
  # on darwin the X server might not be started, or on unix we are working
  # on a console, or whatever.
  eval { my $foo = Tk::MainWindow->new; $foo->destroy; };
  if ($@) {
    printf STDERR "perl/Tk unusable, cannot create main windows.
That could be a consequence of not having X Windows installed or started!
Error message from creating MainWindow:
```

---

at request of Dai Bowen, the $PATH is:

```
/home/*username*/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/share/ImageMagick-7.1.1-2:/usr/sbin/apache2:/usr/lib/apache2:/etc/apache2:/usr/share/apache2:/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/:/usr/bin/inkscape:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/inkscape:/usr/share/inkscape:/usr/share/man/man1/inkscape.1.gz:/opt/Zotero-6.0.22_linux-x86_64:/usr/bin/context:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/context:/usr/share/man/man1/context.1.gz:/usr/sbin/apache2:/usr/lib/apache2:/etc/apache2:/usr/share/apache2:/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/bin/inkscape:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/inkscape:/usr/share/inkscape:/usr/share/man/man1/inkscape.1.gz:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/Zotero-6.0.22_linux-x86_64:/usr/bin/context:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/context:/usr/share/man/man1/context.1.gz:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/:/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/scripts/arara:/opt/Zotero-6.0.22_linux-x86_64:/usr/bin/context:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/context:/usr/share/man/man1/context.1.gz:/usr/sbin/apache2:/usr/lib/apache2:/etc/apache2:/usr/share/apache2:/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz
```

---

After adding the symbolic links as suggested by Dai Bowen, I ran the commands `$tlmgr gui` which worked fine, but it brought me to the GUI for Texlive 2021 version. With the symbolic links *in the path* as suggested, I ran `$sudo tlmgr gui` which yielded this response:

```
username@username-ComputerName:~$ sudo tlmgr gui
[sudo] password for username:            
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
Loading local TeX Live database
  (/root/texmf/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb)
This may take some time, please be patient ...
TLPDB: Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /root/texmf!
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5285.
username@username-ComputerName:~$
```

I looked at `(/root/texmf/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb)` which generated the error. I found that only `/root/texmf` existed, ***not*** the `tlpkg` folder and the file `texlive.tlpdb`

But I did find the desired file at `/usr/local/texlive/2022/tlpkg/texlive.plpdb`.

As a classic example of **"a little knowledge is a dangerous thing"**, I then created a symbolic link inside `/root/texmf` to the latter directory. I then tested it, and *it was of no help whatsoever*. Rather than leave this rather large collection of symbolic links in the `/root/texmf/` directory, I deleted them all. Before I did that, though, I did take the precautionary step of checking in the target directory and all of the original files were still there. So, I followed through and deleted the symbolic links.

**UNFORTUNATELY**, don't ask me how -- all of the files and folders at `/usr/local/texlive/2022/tlpkg/` are now **GONE** and I've got this error message:

```
username@username-ComputerName:~$ sudo /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr gui
[sudo] password for username:            
Can't locate TeXLive/TLConfig.pm in @INC
(you may need to install the TeXLive::TLConfig module)
(@INC contains: /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive     /usr/local/texlive/2022/tlpkg /etc/perl     /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34.0    /usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.34 /usr/share/perl5     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34       /usr/share/perl/5.34 /usr/local/lib/site_perl)
at
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 91.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 91
username@username-ComputerName:~$
```

I did a quick look on CTAN and TUG, but there doesn't seem to be a clear instruction set on how to (re-)install the **TLConfig module**.
Ironically, TLMGR is not going to be of any use for the re-installation :(
Is there perhaps a "repair" method from the TeXLive 2022 DVD? I found this tidbit [TUG TeXlive installation instructions](http://tug.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#installation)wherein it does appear that you can run the installer from the DVD with the command `install -tl -in-place`; it sounds like the installer will look at what you've got, and create the `tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb`  files and folders

Comment: The `running on Debian` and those paths (`/usr/bin/tlmgr`, `/usr/share/doc/texlive-base/`) means you're back [on the Debian-packaged texlive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/624378/106162). Did you follow the previous suggestion of [pre-pending the `/usr/local`-based texlive path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676880/106162)?  What does `$PATH` show?

Comment: D'oh. Thanks for spotting that so quickly. I've had so much computer-related stuff going on these few days that I must've over-written those synapses formed last month. So to answer your questions 1) Yes, it works if I pre-pend; and 2) I edited my question to show the (verbose!) $PATH. Also, it doesn't help at all if I change the ``sudoers`` default path to include the path to the non-Debian ``tlmgr`` ---- it still picks up the Debian version if I run from ``$ sudo tlmgr gui``

Comment: PS--I tried to get some help at SUPERUSER.COM regarding my $PATH, which has repeated entries, because I over-zealously appended the ``export PATH=...`` in several ``bash`` and ``profile`` files. My question was shut down by the moderator. I was trying to find out what sequence is followed in building the $PATH, and the effect (if any) of having those repeated entries, so that I could go back and prune the ``export PATH=...`` commands.

Comment: Your `$PATH` shows `/usr/bin` before `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux`, so it's going to find the wrong `tlmgr` first. You could add symlinks to the texlive binaries in `/home/<user>/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` as they appear earlier rather than further modify PATH.

Comment: I've added the symbolic link to the directory ``~/<username>/bin``   but it doesn;t seem to make a difference. It may need a re-start. I will let you know if that changes.

Comment: No, restarting did not change the results; from terminal ``$ tlmgr gui`` till took me to the 2021 version, not the 2022 version.

Comment: But, I extrapolated your comment about using symbolic links and this led me to make a big mistake, which is entirely my own. I will have to Edit the original question to add sufficient details---please see....

Comment: First: see edits of main question. I need some advice on the possibility of using the TeXLive DVD, which may work for repair

Comment: A possibility: As long as the PATH is acceptable for binaries, you may be able to correct where TeX looks for its internals, by defining them in your `~.bashrc` file. So if you define TeX internal `export TEXMFROOT=/path/to/texlive/year` then reboot, TeX will look in there. Some other TeX internals are derived from `TEXMFROOT` but may also be defined individually.

Comment: Update re: lost files: I had upgraded to a larger HDD about 2 weeks ago, and it was untouched, so I had the not-so-brilliant idea that I could restore the lost ```tlpkg``` files from there; ```tlmgr``` now works (so long as I use the full path to it)

Comment: rallg: thanks for taking the time to make that suggestion; I added ```export TEXMFROOT=/usr/local/texlive/2022```, then ran ```source ~/.bashrc```, then ```$ tlmgr gui``` and ```$ sudo tlmgr gui```. In both cases, it still picked up the 2021 version.